# Compile C++ file with Python.h import using Bazel

Tags: python, c++, g++, bazel

I want to compile a C++ file which uses Python embedding. Therefore I #include  in my C++ source. When using g++ as compiler I would specify the following flags:

g++ -o pybridge pybridge.cc -I/usr/include/python2.7/ -lpython2.7

I want to use Bazel for compilation now and tried the following target rule:

```
cc_binary(
  name = "pybridge",
  srcs = ["pybridge.cc"],
  copts = ["-I/usr/include/python2.7/"],
  linkopts = ["-lpython2.7"]
)
```

Running `bazel build` gives error messages like this:

`pybridge.cc:(.text+0x10): undefined reference to Py_Initialize`

Comment: Can you send the output of bazel -s to see the command? Also what happens if you build without sandboxing (`--spawn_strategy=standalone`)? Do you know where is the libpython2.7.so on the file system?

Answer (score 1):

Bazel executes your build in a sandbox, to prevent it from accessing random resources on your system that won't be present on, say, your coworker's system.

This means that, unless you've declared a file (like the Python library) as a dependency, Bazel won't put it in the sandbox and your build won't be able to find it.

There are two options:

The easy one is to build with `--spawn_strategy=standalone` (`bazel build --spawn_strategy=standalone :pybridge`).  This tells Bazel not to use sandboxing for this build.  Note that, as far as Bazel knows, nothing has changed between the sandboxed and non-sandboxed run, so you'll have to clean before re-running without sandboxing, or you'll just get the cached error.

The harder option is to declare `/usr/lib/libpython2.7.so` as an input to your build.  If you want to do that, add the following to the WORKSPACE file:

```
local_repository(
    name = "system_python",
    path = "/usr/lib/python2.7/config-x86_64-linux-gnu", # Figure out where it is on your system, this is where it is on mine
    build_file_content = """
cc_library(
   name = "my-python-lib",
   srcs = ["libpython2.7.so"],
   visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)
""",
)
```

Then in your BUILD file, instead of `linkopts = ["-lpython2.7"]`, add `deps = ["@system_python//:my-python-lib"]`.  Then Bazel will understand that your build depends on libpython2.7.so (and include it in the sandbox).

Answer (score 0):

(*Tried commenting on OP's post but I lack the required karma.*)

FWIW, I've had problems linking against Python 2.7's libraries (on Windows), even when I didn't use Bazel but ran the linker manually, so this problem may be unrelated to Bazel.